# proc events not arriving over netlink connector (forkstat)

Tags: linux-kernel

**Kernel 3.14 stable-79.**

I wish to trace fork(2) and related events using [forkstat](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/cking/forkstat.git/). For some
reason no events arrive over the socket. `strace` shows
that it hangs indefinitely in `recv(2)`:

```
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 5), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb775d000
write(1, "Time     Event  PID  Info  Durat"..., 44Time     Event  PID  Info  Duration Process) = 44
sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO)      = 99
sched_setscheduler(17458, SCHED_FIFO, { 99 }) = 0
recv(3,
```

On another box with a 4.4-ish kernel this works just fine.

What’s missing here? Doest the connector require some `sysctl`?

Comment: PS someone please create the “netlink” tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the config. Turns out, `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS` is a prerequisite
of these things but unset. In addition, I had to switch `CONFIG_CONNECTOR`
from module to compiled in. Thus the require change to the config looks
as follows:

```
-CONFIG_CONNECTOR=m
+# forkstat requires this
+CONFIG_CONNECTOR=y
+CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y
```